# Retrieve Custom Claims in Blazor Client Web Assembly via AuthenticationState

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a hosted Blazor web assembly project that has an asp.net core API along w/ some razor pages, etc.  I am adding custom claims server side via an `IClaimsTransformation` object which is registered via DI in the `Startup.cs` file.  That is all working server side, however, I'd like to get the same claims on the Blazor client as well.  We are using Azure Active Directory for authentication which is also working out fine.

The problem comes when trying to access the `AuthenticationState` on the Blazor client side. It is null and not sure why this is occurring. Using a `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` in the App.razor file and then referencing that value by injecting the cascading parameter inside a Blazor component with the following:

```
[CascadingParameter] AuthenticationState authState { get; set; }
```

Ultimately the goal is to gain access to the user claims principle cascaded down.

Here is the App.razor code:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: IIRC the cascading parameter needs to be of type Task<AuthenticationState>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter